# HtmlAgilityPack and BeautifulSoup missing tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, f#, screen-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am scraping this site:  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/press-releases.
In the browser, there are 20+ articles.  However, when I pull the site's HTML down and load it into HTML agility pack, only the first three articles are appearing.

```
let client = new WebClient()
let uri = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/press-releases"
let response = client.DownloadString(uri)
let doc = HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(response)
```

works:

```
let node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"summaryPressStream-0-Stream\"]/ul/li[1]")
node.InnerText
```

no works:

```
let node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"summaryPressStream-0-Stream\"]/ul/li[10]")
node.InnerText
```

Is it because there are some jenky li tags in the yahoo site?  Is it is limitation of the HtmlAgilityPack?

I also did the same script in Python using BeautifulSoup and have the same problem:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/press-releases?"
page = urlopen(url)
html = page.read().decode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(link['href'])
```

Thanks

Comment: The missing articles are loaded via javascript which is not executed when requesting via `urlopen`. You'll need something that runs javascript such as Selenium.